# Why would an animated scroll to anchor, cause a jittering on iPad when trying to scroll afterwards?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code that successfully scrolls to an anchor link on click. For some reason, this same code is causing a weird jittery effect on iPad. If you click on an anchor link, scroll to it and then try to drag the screen to scroll the whole site flashes and doesn't let you scroll up.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#"]', function() {
  if ($(window).width() > 1024) {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top - 57
    }, 500);
  } else {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top - 49
    }, 500);
  }
  return false;
});
```

Comment: A stab in the dark: `animate` installs event handlers and fails to remove one when the animation ends. The handler is responding to and interfering with scrolling, probably because something is preventing recognition of completion of the animation. If debugging `animate` isn't something you want to do and you are obliged to support iPads then don't use `animate`.

Comment: @PeterWone Thanks for sharing some advise. I will look into .animate to see if I can find a solution.